# Fourier transformations and the inversion formula

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

[image]

I am working through the above question in preparation for an upcoming exam. I have completed part (a) and quoted the inversion formula for part (b), but I cannot see how to find a form to evaluate the integral. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for part (a) should be
$$\frac{1-ik}{1+k^2}$$

So by the inversion formula
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1-ik}{1+k^2} e^{ikx}\,dk$$

Now separate the integrand into real part and imaginary part. Notice that $f(x)$ is a real function, so the imaginary part in the integrand should be zero. The real part is exactly the integral in part (b). Can you go on from here?

Comment: Sorry to bump this up, but was the answer just  $\pi f(x)$?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours: Yes.